# How can i conditionally format a whole column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

[image]

I want the right column to get a bold font whenever the left column is bigger.

For example: `0` should be bold and `59` should be bold in the right column.

Whenever I try it I add a range and then choose `'smaller than'` and I choose the range of the left column it adds the complete column and compares it to the complete other column. I want them to be compared individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

- Format.
- Conditional Formatting.
- In the field "Apply to range" fill in the range that you want to apply these formatting rules on.  For example column B:B.
- select "Greater than" in the "Format cells if..." drop-down box. Fill in the "value or formula box" the 1st cell that you want to check. For example =A1.
- Change the Formatting style to Bold

And you're done.

Go [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1On_ywO9KZjpfuT_1K3xn50oUhBLed-6YMYAmOvcQclU/edit?usp=sharing) for a live example, copy it to your own drive and have fun!

Comment: This would mean i have to do every cell individually. What i meant is that i want Sheets to compare column x:y with the cell that is left of theirs. It should be possible to add a row and that the condition gets checked automatically. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is not true, checkout the live example and check it out yourself.

Comment: @danielrieske's answer is actually correct (except that you want to highlight B:B and compare it to A1 using 'Less than'). The key thing is that you put =(whatever is the top cell in column A), not the whole range of cells, and it will automatically adjust the rule for all the other cells using relative addressing.

Comment: @TomSharpe You are absolutely right, I changed that in my example and answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Could you make the document editable? I can only copy it, and i would like to see what you mean in the sheet it self. I cant seem to get it working.

Comment: @MartijnvandenBergh No problem at all. Make sure to mark this as the right answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom formula. In the example below I limited the range to D13:D22 and added the green color for clarity.

Even though the formula says "apply the format if `D13<C13`" it works like an `arrayformula` and applies it to the whole range cell by cell as you need.

[image]

Comment: This was almost my case. I had to put D1 < C1 instead. It looks like it needs the first row by some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Select the 'right' column and apply a CF Custom formula rule to the effect:

```
=right column top cell < left column top cell
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario and what I think was the original goal, was to ensure the custom formula applied to 2 separate rows in their entirety - otherwise the user would need to write the custom formula for each line. In order to achieve this goal automatically, I was able to apply the forumla to the first row only and then use Google sheet's native embedded logic to apply the formula to the both columns. Example: I have column A which is actual price of something and column B which is a price threshold. Note, in column A there are multiple items with different respective prices. I want the respective row in column B to turn green (as opposed to being bold as mentioned in this thread) when the price threshold met. I would highlight Cell A1 (first cell of my price data) and apply the formula here; Format > conditional formatting > Apply to range = A1 (the cell which should turn green), Format cells if = customer formula is > =$A1<=$B2. This states that if the price/value of A1 is less than or equal to B2 then turn Green. Right, this applies it to these 2 cells only. We want to apply this logic to the whole column A and B. To do this, we select A1 and click the circle on the bottom right hand corner and swipe all the way down to the end of the column (A in this example). If you select any cell in column A. The logic will work however the logic within each cell will not need to update.